# Spring Batch produces no logging output when launched from the command line

Tags: java, maven, logging, spring-batch, log4j2

As the title describes, no logs are getting produced when I launch my Spring Batch jobs from the command line.

Background info:

- The logging framework that I'm using: log4j2
- Logging *usually* works fine when launched from within Eclipse (manual logging is done via `Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class)`). Sometimes, however, it also randomly doesn't work. This problem seems to occur when I run a maven "install", and it vanishes if I do a simple maven "clean"
- I'm not using all of Spring Boot (too much overhead); see my dependencies below
- The command I'm using to launch my jobs once they're built:
  `"C:/path/to/java.exe" -cp "target/dependency-jars/*;target/my.jar" org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner my.package.my.Config jobName parameters=values`

My `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        <!-- exclude the default, which is logback, not log4j2 -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do you see the `log4j2` jar in `dependency-jars` directory? If not, try running `mvn dependency:tree` and see if it is imported. Otherwise, try with only spring batch core dependency and see what happens (to isolate the issue): `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: I see `log4j-api-2.10.0.jar`, `log4j-core-2.10.0.jar` and `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar` in my `target/dependency-jars/` directory.

Comment: ok thanks. Can you try by adding only the dependency to `spring-batch-core` and see if the logs appear? Just trying to isolate the issue..

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine what happens when I only include the spring batch core dependency is errors, because `org.apache.logging.log4j.[stuff]` cannot be resolved (for obvious reasons). Side note: removing the `<exclusion>` causes `StackOverflowErrors`, so that's not an option either.

Comment: well, with only the dependency to the core module, I see logs without errors (See https://gist.github.com/benas/d267f5f0c86efd61d6e0904148778572). You should have a classpath issue which I'm not able see.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine fair enough, I get similar logs, once I remove all of *my* logging calls. Try creating a logger so that you can call `logger.info(...)` or something like that - the dependency won't get resolved, or at least that's what happens to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179802/discussion-between-pixelmaster-and-mahmoud-ben-hassine).

Comment: I updated the example with log4j2. See details in the chat. Hope it helps.

Comment: I found the problem, it was a dependencies issue. I'm rather busy at the moment, though; I got a deadline on friday. I'll post an answer detailing my solution here afterwards.

Comment: @PixelMaster Can you post your answer?

Comment: @AbhinandanMadaan I'm afraid not, unfortunately I seem to have forgotten to actually post my solution back then (shame on me). Anyway, I haven't touched that code in at least 1.5 years, so I only vaguely remember that I had this issue at all. Did you check the chat discussion linked above? Maybe something in there could help you solve your issue :/

Comment: I had a similar problem and answered it here, if anyone is facing a similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68217675/spring-batch-not-executing-stepexecutionlistener-beforestep-or-afterstep-methods/68250833#68250833