# Spring Batch not executing StepExecutionListener beforeStep or afterStep methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

**Update:** I was re-running my code and actually noticed none of my Listeners are actually working...

I have a Spring Batch application and I am overriding the StepExecutionListener and providing my own implementation. I am registering it with the TaskletStep, however, I never see the log messages that the beforeStep/afterStep methods should be outputting:

**MyStepExecutionListener.java**

```
public class MyStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {

 @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // begin my own custom implementation
        LOGGER.info("Before the step!");
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
         // begin my own custom implementation
         LOGGER.info("After the step!");
        return stepExecution.getStatus();

    }
}
```

I have defined my Tasklet Step in my **BatchConfig.java** class as:

```
public BatchConfig {

@Bean
    public static org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope jobScope() {
        org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope jobScope = new org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope();
        jobScope.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        jobScope.setAutoProxy(true);
        return jobScope;
    }

    @Bean
    public static org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope stepScope() {
        org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope stepScope = new org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope();
        stepScope.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        stepScope.setAutoProxy(true);
        return stepScope;
    }

    @Bean
//    @StepScope
    public StepExecutionListener stepExecutionListener() {
        return new MyStepExecutionListener();
    }

 @Bean
    @Qualifier("s3FlatfFileReaderForMktgOffrs")
    @StepScope
    public S3FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> s3FlatfFileReaderForMktgOffrs() {
        return new S3FlatFileItemReader<>(lineMapper());
    }

 @Bean
    @Qualifier("s3FlatfFileReaderCustom")
    @StepScope
    public S3FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> s3FlatfFileReaderCustom() {
        // Custom class that Extends FlatFileItemReader
        return new S3FlatFileItemReader<>(lineMapper());
    }

  @Bean
    @Qualifier("myCustomFileItemReader")
    @StepScope
    public ItemStreamReader<List<FieldSet>> myCustomFileItemReader(
            @Value("#{jobParameters}") Map jobParameters) {

        String fileName = (String) jobParameters.get("fileName");
        String region = (String) jobParameters.get("region");
        String bucketName = awsS3EastBucket;
        if (StringUtils.equals(region, Regions.US_WEST_2.getName())) {
            bucketName = awsS3WestBucket;
        }

        // Custom class that Extends FlatFileItemReader
        S3FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> s3FileItemReader = s3FlatfFileReaderCustom();

     
         s3FileItemReader.setResource(S3_PROTOCOL_PREFIX + bucketName + SLASH + fileName);
        }

        s3FileItemReader.setStrict(false);
        s3FileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        s3FileItemReader.setSaveState(false);

        AggregateItemReader aggregateItemReader = new AggregateItemReader(s3FileItemReader) {
            @Override
            protected String getItemKey(FieldSet item) {
                return item.readString(FIRST_NAME) + "-" +
                        item.readString(LAST_NAME);
            }
        };
        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<List<FieldSet>> fieldSetSynchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
        fieldSetSynchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(aggregateItemReader);
        return fieldSetSynchronizedItemStreamReader;
    }



@Bean(name = "myCustomStep")
    @Scope("prototype")
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Step myCustomStep(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        TaskletStep step = stepBuilderFactory.get("myCustomStep")
                .<List<FieldSet>, List<MyPayLoadRecord>>chunk(250)
                .reader(myCustomFileItemReader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                .processor(myCustomProcessor())
                .writer(myCustomWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipPolicy(new AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy())
                .skip(DataValidationException.class)
                .listener(stepExecutionListener())
                .listener(new CustomReaderListener())
                .listener(new CustomProcessListener())
                .listener(new CustomWriteListener())
                .listener(new CustomSkipListener())
                .taskExecutor(batchTaskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(maxThreads)
                .build();
        step.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        //step.registerStepExecutionListener(stepExecutionListener());
        step.registerChunkListener(new CustomChunkListener());
        return step;
    }
}
```

I have commented out `step.registerStepExecutionListener(stepExecutionListener());` and tried setting the listener as seen above, but neither implementation worked. I was under the impression I should just implement the StepExecutionListener then register it with the TaskletStep - am I missing something here?

Comment: How is `stepExecutionListener()` defined?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I added the Bean definition for it up above now !

Comment: How are you verifying that a listener "works"? Breakpoints in a debug session, or just checking the logs? (If the second, have you confirmed that your logging levels are correctly configured? Easiest way would be to put a logging statement in the MyStepExecutionListener's constructor)

Comment: Also your `afterStep` method is missing its return statement, so it shouldn't even be compiling.

Comment: A step should have @JobScope and I am not understanding why are you using @Scope("prototype")?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have logs in the Before/After step that should be logging after I run a batch insert, but its not there. I added the return to afterStep(), I missed it here because I was just copying the code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the reason for making your step as a prototype-scoped bean, but I'm not able to reproduce the issue with a setup similar to what you shared (using Spring Batch v4.3.3). Here is a quick example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SO68217675 {

    @Bean
//    @StepScope // works with a step-scoped bean as well
    public StepExecutionListener stepExecutionListener() {
        return new MyStepExecutionListener();
    }

    @Bean
//    @Scope("prototype") // works with a prototype bean as well, but I don't understand the reason for that scope
    public Step step(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(2)
                .reader(new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)))
                .writer(items -> items.forEach(System.out::println))
                .listener(stepExecutionListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step(stepBuilderFactory))
                .build();
    }

    static class MyStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {

        @Override
        public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            System.out.println("MyStepExecutionListener.beforeStep");
        }

        @Override
        public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            System.out.println("MyStepExecutionListener.afterStep");
            return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SO68217675.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

This example prints the following (as expected):

```
MyStepExecutionListener.beforeStep
1
2
3
4
MyStepExecutionListener.afterStep
```

Comment: I added the method implementation of my stepScope and jobScope, also I had a weird output when my App boots up regarding my Reader method: 

org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader is an interface. The implementing class will not be queried for annotation based listener configurations. If using StepScope on a Bean method, be sure to return the implementing class so listener annotations can be used.

Comment: I am actually returning a SynchronizedItemStreamReader<List<FieldSet>> in my reader method so I changed the method signature from the ItemStreamReader to that, and it seems to remove the error message but I still don't see the steps logged.  I feel like this might be related to the Reader or maybe all the proxy/step/job scopes being used.

Comment: So far , the only way I am able to get any Listener to work is by directly implementing the "StepExecutionListener" on a class like "myCustomProcessor()". It seems like there is something with the way my configuration is defined that the Listener methods aren't able to be found/called the Spring batch framework when I define these listener in separate classes and try to register them with the TaskletStep, i.e. "beforeStep/afterStep"

Comment: well that's super weird - I found the problem. I re-read your answer (thank you again) and played around and added the Listener in my BatchConfiguration.java class where all the Beans for the Batch job are at. I used a STATIC NESTED class like you did for the StepListener, and guess what? It works! I'm still a little perplexed as to why returning the custom Class for the StepListener defined outside of this BatchConfiguration does not work though... Can the framework not find it or something? I figured defining the StepListener as a Bean would add it to the IoC

Comment: yikes, I see more clearly now the  Listeners were working the entire time. I thought they weren't, because I have LOGGERS in the before/after methods and they never logged.  But I threw a System.outprint.ln and I see its working, so the problem is with the LOGGER. Using the static nested class help me find this out. Still not sure why this is the case, but oh well

Comment: I found the problem. You helped me with the static class implementation of the listener, which helped me find problem. I will Post my solution here, but give you best answer. Thank you.

Comment: is Spring Batch using some type of specific logging? I was using log4j2 (with log4j2.xml on classpath config). The only way I can get the Listeners (Step/Job/Chunk) to work from external classes (not static class defined in BatchConfiguration) is to remove the exclusion for "spring-boot-starter-logging" under all the spring-boot-starters, which is recommended if using log4j2 instead of logback. Only issue is this breaks my log4j2.xml config, and I no longer get RollingLogs to my Log folder. I  guess I could try logback, or just settle for Static nested classes for time being

Answer (score 0):

Per @MahmoudBenHassine answer - By implementing the Listener (Step or any of them) as a static nested class, I was able to use the Slf4j LOGGER already in my BatchConfiguration.java class, and see that *indeed the Listeners **were working***. Though, I was still perplexed why this seem to **not** work when I defined the Listener in its own package/class. I then started to suspect the LOGGERS, as basically, this was how I was verifying whether it was "working or not". Thus, I placed some System.out.println("") dummy output in my StepExecutionerListener (the one I was having issues with that was defined in its own custom Class/package) and ***lo-and-behold***, I saw the output.

***Thus, the Listeners were working the entire time***, however, the LOGGERS were NOT working, and my validation methodology was inferior, as it was shadowing/hiding the main problem (using the LOGGERS as proof of whether the Step/Chunk/Job Listener was working or not).

Per this post, it made me more curious something was wrong with my slf4j/log4j dependencies in my POM or maybe I was missing something:

[Spring Batch produces no logging output when launched from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261024/spring-batch-produces-no-logging-output-when-launched-from-the-command-line)

Furthermore, I setup my POM.xml in a way for logging per this Article, which recommended removing all the `spring-boot-starter-logging` from ALL the spring-boot-starters (which I did), and adding 1 `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` dependency if you plan to use log4j (like I did):

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging

Anyway, I removed the `<exclusion>` for the `spring-boot-starter-logging` inside my `spring-boot-starter-batch` dependency defined in my POM and the Logging is working fine now (it seems) in the custom class Listeners (Step/Chunk/Job) now.

When I examine my project dependencies in IntelliJ I have:

```
log4j:log4j:1.2.15
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.3
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.13.3
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:2.13.3
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.13.3
org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.30
org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.30
org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.30
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
```

I noticed by removing the exclusion on the spring-boot-starter-batch, as mentioned above, I saw this dependency get added:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.13.3
```

So I'm assuming Spring Batch need's this when triggering the listeners `before/after` methods for LOGGING. Hope this helps anyone!